# Jquery, variable undefined

Tags: jquery, variables, undefined

so i got this little code and i can't get it working and i simply can't see why. I've copied the code from another code i wrote and only removed and renamed all the stuff that i don't need. I want to give out the value of a variable in an alert box.

The JS:

```
<script>
     function ready2() {
         var rdy = $("#rdy").value;
         alert(rdy); 
     }
</script>
```

The HTML:

> ```
> <body>
>    <form id="form2" onsubmit="return false;">
>       <div>Ready:</div>
>       <input type="text" id="rdy"></input>
>       <button id="btn" onclick="ready2()">Ready</button>
>    </form>
> </body>
> ```

If I replace  `$("#rdy").value;` with something like "hello world", it works. So the problem must be the variable or better: the input box. The alert box always says "undefined" and I don't know why.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need this -

```
var rdy = $("#rdy").val();
```

or

```
var rdy = $("#rdy")[0].value;
```

you can use `value` only on DOM element, You are getting undefined because you are using it on jquery object i.e - `$("#rdy")`

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
$("#rdy")
```

You are actually generating a jQuery Object array with all the nodes in it:

```
[domNode1, domNode2,... domNodeN] 
//note this array is a jQuery object, not an Array
```

Since it is an ID it should only find one:

```
[domNodeWithIdrdy]
```

The DOM node inside the jquery array is the same as if you do `getElementById` which means that you can access the values directly:

```
var jArray = $("#rdy");
console.log(jArray[0].value);
```

jQuery also provides some functions that do this:

```
$("#rdy").value();
```

But bare in mind that the `val()` function will only return the value of the first element in your jquery Array, and ignore the presence of multiple elements on the array.

It is also safer to do `.val()` than to do `jArray[0].value`. This because if the array is empty it will try to read `value` out of `undefined`. i.e.:

```
jArray = $("#somethingThatDoesntExist");
assert( jArray.length === 0 );
assert( jArray[0] === undefined );
```

Comment: it's `.val()` not `.value()`